# Is there a reconstruction of the Titanomachy (as in the epic poem)?

Tags: greek, reference-request, epic-poetry

I have access to the fragments of the Titanomachy.

I have a short commentary on the Titanomachy in the book: The Greek Epic Cycle by Malcolm Davies, thanks to Gullintanni (a stack exchange username). Analysis, commentary or interpretation that will help give understanding to the Titanomachy will be welcome as well.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Martin West's Loeb volume Greek Epic Fragments collects all the available fragments for the Titanomachy and a short introduction (2 paragraphs) on it. This is also where you'll find all the available fragments for early Greek epic.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, as far as you are aware, there is no reconstruction available?

Comment: @Stewart What do you mean by reconstruction? He collected all the fragments and references to it, so it's about as clear of a reconstruction as we can get without making things up.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  

I used the term reconstruction to mean: to glean more from the fragments than they would first suggest. 
     
I have not yet (although planning to) read the following books, however my understanding is that the Leob Greek epic fragments book does not necessarily give as much of a reconstruction as is possible (it’s not its purpose anyway). For example, it has much less information about the Cypria than “The Cypria: Reconstructing the Lost Prequel to Homer's Iliad” by D.M. Smith.

Comment: @Yes, it's a collection of fragments. Reconstructions of the sort you want often involve highly subjective conjectures, whereas the Loebs are more conservative in their reconstruction. Not sure if any of the former type exist for the titanomachy, though I think West in his Oxford commentary on Hesiod's Theogony might have some of what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for that informative comment. Sorry, however I do not know which book you are referring to when you write: ”West in his Oxford commentary on Hesiod's Theogony”.

Comment: @Stewart Actually, I looked today in it, and it doesn't go into Eumelus' *Titanomachy* at all. Sorry.